# If you consume a lot of protein but don't exercise does it go to waste?

Tags: diet, nutrition, bodybuilding, protein

I recently had surgery and have been asked to avoid exercise for atleast 4 weeks. Before surgery I was doing moderate weight lifting and cardio several times a week and consuming 200 grams of protein a day mainly from eggs and shakes. I am still taking the same amount of protein daily but was wondering if it's going to waste now that I am not exercising at all.

So if one doesn't work out what happens with the protein? Does the body use just a smaller amount and expell the rest as waste or does it get stored at fat, etc.?

My weight is 180lbs and height is 5.8'

Comment: Why would you keep your diet the same if you're not expending the same number of calories?

Comment: Short answer...yes; the excess protein that the body can't digest will turn into fat.

Comment: Not necessarily. If that were the case I would have been putting on fat going to AYCE sushi on a regular basis with no exercise.

Comment: @RobinAshe - Andreas is correct. Short answer - yes. Long one - no. Point is that body **can't** store proteins, but can convert them into carbs which then can be stored as fat. Devil here is - to get fat from protein, body needs a lot of energy and in this case caloric value of protein is much more closer to 2-3 kcal then to 4 kcal.

Comment: @StupidOne even so, according to that I would have been putting on fat. the calorie hypothesis is grossly oversimplified, and the claim that it'll get converted to fat ignores the fact that we have bowel movements

Comment: @RobinAshe As long as you are not in caloric surplus, you won't gain any weight. To talk about amount or even weight of food and in the same time ignoring caloric value when we are talking about storing / loosing fat is next to pointless.

Comment: @StupidOne I was in a supposed calorie surplus of several thousand per day, and wasn't gaining any weight. Conversely, there are people on calorie deficits who gain weight. Using calories to predict anything is pointless.

Comment: @RobinAshe In that case, you are walking miracle as law of conservation of energy doesn't apply to you.

Comment: @StupidOne nope, it's just that calories, if the hypothesis has any validity at all, work in a far more complex fashion than 99% of people who give advice based on calories understand

Comment: @RobinAshe Can you provide any white paper which backs up your claim? We can talk about playing with carb intake, but in the most casses, only when body fat is 10% or lower. Also, when we are talking about body composition, physical preformance, TEF, choleserol, oxidative stress, hormon balance and so on, then source of calories DO metter. But in the terms of weight loss (or gain) a calorie is simply a calorie. [Weight Loss Fudamentals](http://www.bodyrecomposition.com/fat-loss/the-fundamentals-of-fat-loss-diets-part-1.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define waste.

You may or may not gain weight, but there are other considerations at play. Excessive caloric intake will *probably* cause you to gain weight, plus there are other metabolic considerations from the reduction in exercise that may have an affect as well.

When you have an excessive amount of protein intake, then you start placing a larger burden on the liver (deamination of the proteins) and the kidneys (excretion of the excess ammonia converted to urea), as well as being converted to glucose and ketones in the body.

It can have an affect on blood acidity, which in turn can cause calcium loss as the body tries to normalize blood pH.

If you can't exercise for a period of time, I would reduce all your macro-nutrients in proportion, then resume your regular diet when you can get back to full activity. There have been a few questions on the site on how to start back after a period off, as your strength and conditioning will fade a bit.

While it is a *very* general rule of thumb, personal observation and kinesiology classes that I've taken suggest that most people are ok with up to 7 days being off and having minimal losses. After that, it will take two days to gain back for every day you were off. Some people have greater losses, some have less, it all depends on your body.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, all things being equal, your body will convert the excess protein into fat, which will be stored in the body.

I would recommend that you reduce your intake while your not exercising to prevent weight gain.  Protein is a good, but have less.

Comment: Totally incorrect protein is not converted to fat

Comment: Protein can be converted into acetyl-coA, which can then be converted into fatty acids or glycogen.  Therefore, protein can indeed be converted in to fat.  Unfortunately fat cannot be converted back into protein though.

Comment: Sorry excess protein comes out in urine, not to say that it is good for u

Comment: hey you removed the goodbye noob part, I took the question to mean "if I take too much whey protein" will I gain fat, and from experience and what I've read I don't think that you will gain weight from that

Comment: The nitrogen part of the amino acids gets excreted as urea in the urine, not the whole molecule or protein